# Powershell to create folders and files(text files) from CSV

Tags: powershell

I need to create separate folders based on the CSV file.

CSV File has 2 headers:

```
Name and BLOB
Name1    BLOB1
Name2    BLOB2
```

I need to create folders for all the names listed in the NAME header and text files for all the text files listed in the BLOB header. It needs to be like the below:

Name1(Item type is directory) inside this folder is BLOB1(item type is text file)

```
Set-Location "D:\SC"
$FoldersOrder = Import-Csv D:\SC\CSV\test.csv
ForEach ($Folder in $FoldersOrder) { 
    New-Item $Folder.Order -type directory ; New-Item -ItemType File $Folder.BLOB
}
```

When I run the command above, it creates folders for NAME header and text files for BLOB header but not inside its respective NAME header folder.

Comment: If you (re-)read the help for [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7) carefully you will learn that there is a paramter `-Path` and `-Name`. So you can specify the path and the name of the files you want to create. I'd recommend as well to use the parameter names in your command lines.  ;-)

Comment: Hi Olaf, For the folder part, it the folder name works as intended "NAME1".

Comment: What Olaf is saying is you need to use the `-path` parameter to include the newly created `$Folder.Order` path. E.G. `-Path "$($Folder.Order)\$($Folder.BLOB).txt"`. Check the command help with `Get-Help New-Item`.

Comment: Omg thank you so much!